# "What would you define as a security event and a security incident and is there is a difference between them"?

Tags: windows, networking, security, cisco, cisco-vpn

"What would you define as a security event and a security incident and is there is a difference between them"? 
In terms of network "firewall" security.

Comment: Any question that can be so completely answered by a single wikipedia link is an indication that you need to work on your google-fu

Comment: You've simply reposted a very vague and possibly subjective question that has been closed so at least 5 people thought it was not good enough to keep open. And you've made no attempt to do any research, even going so far as to openly acknowledge that you weren't willing to search for some enlightenment first.

Comment: I do not have that power (few do), but I have got the power to remember the login name of someone who consistently posts badly-worded questions. And how is it preposterous to point out to someone who comes here for answers that they need to write their questions better if they want good responses? It's called helping, you clearly don't think you need it.

Comment: Wildchild, don't take the closed question personally.  In your other question you admit to eschewing googling for the answer;  that's not really acceptable on the SO-trilogy.  You need to put forth some effort and then if you still have a question show the work you've done.  I would recommend deleting your little ad hominem in this question, clean up your grammar, and move on with your life.

Comment: may be, i got little carried away. But i really appreaciate the quality of answers i have got in the past from SF and expect the same in future.

I thank chopper3 for being supportive although he's irritated lately b'cause of my snarky questions.

I will come up with good doubts next time for sure..
thanks again to all!

Comment: From my perspective it looks like you don't really understand these things.  That's cool, we all start somewhere.  However, it also looks an awful lot like you're not making an effort to understand them, and that's not cool.  Plus your questions are smelling quite strongly of homework, which in general we don't like - we're busy people, after all.  This one is going to close soon, but - *if* you want to ask again - at least show that you're trying yourself instead of just looking for a canned answer.

Comment: @ thepocketwade--I 'm sorry to hop in again.I just want to know if there is any good link /forum online where in i can discuss or learn things related to firewall security. thanks in advance.

Comment: @ mh-- I 've been googling a lot ,but there are plethora of sites which in turn makes me confused.
I completlely trust the links experts give here considering they are way much experianced.
I appologize for not trying hard b'fore posting here. I will make a note of it. And i greatly appreciate the time you guys have been giving me for over 2 months..thank yu

Comment: Just show us in the question that you've tried, and if it's homework admit it straight up (otherwise reconsider your wording) and all will be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_security_incident_management